# How to properly find Non-GAAP diluted earnings per share from earnings release?

Tags: corporate-earnings, earnings-per-share

I looked through Amazon's third quarter earnings release and could not figure out how to properly find the Non-GAAP diluted earnings per share. Sources such as [Zacks](https://www.zacks.com/stock/chart/AMZN/fundamental/eps-diluted) reported it as 0.85. How can I calculate the correct value from the earnings release?
https://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20231025191880/en/